# How can I make apt-cache show, only, a list of the installed packages?

Tags: apt

I ran this command:

```
apt-cache rdepends my-package-here
```

The results included apps that I haven't installed in my setup. I only would like to see the packages that have been installed.

Answer (score 4):

According to [apt-cache man](http://--installed%20Limit%20the%20output%20of%20depends%20and%20rdepends%20to%20packages%20which%20are%20currently%20installed.%20Configuration%20Item:%20APT::Cache::Installed.) the flags:

```
--depends pkg...
depends shows a listing of each dependency a package has and all the possible other packages that can fulfill that dependency.
--rdepends pkg...
rdepends shows a listing of each reverse dependency a package has.
--installed
Limit the output of depends and rdepends to packages which are currently installed. Configuration Item: APT::Cache::Installed.
```

You can use this command:

```
apt-cache --installed rdepends my-package-here
my-package-here
  Depends: something
  Depends: something
  Depends: something
  Depends: something
  Depends: something
  Depends: something
  Depends: something
```

Answer (score 1):

> if you want to only show the packages installed on your system

Use the following command instead:

```
apt-rdepends --state-follow=Installed --state-show=Installed package_name
```

[man apt-rdepends](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/apt-rdepends.1.html)